# Handling timeout gracefully on Observable.FromAsyncPattern

Tags: c#, exception, system.reactive

I'm making an observable out of an AsyncPattern, which I want to keep polling at intervals. So far I've got to here:

```
var observer = Observable.Defer(ObservableFunc)
    .Concat(Observable.Empty<int>().Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_pollInterval)))
    .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_Timeout_s))
    .Materialize()
    .Repeat()
    .Publish()
    .RefCount();
```

- Don't poll until someone subscribes (`Defer`)
- re-poll a given time after last response (and not just [keep blindly polling](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/rx/thread/52e3744e-cb18-4745-951f-51596a0f3b2d)) (`Concat/Delay`)
- Detect if the poll has timed out (no answer) (`Timeout`)
- Start again if it *does* time out (`Repeat`)
- Don't re-subscribe [for new subscribers](http://nascentcode.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/creating-a-shared-refcounted-observable/), stop polling when there are no more subscribers (`Publish/RefCount`).

My question is about the `Materialize` in the middle there. This (to me), seems to be a fairly elegant way of letting the TimeoutException 'through' so that the subscribers can know about it. I'm just not sure whether I should let it carry on as a `Notification`, or maybe re-materialize it into some kind of `Maybe/Nullable T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not "qualify" as an answer, but probably too long for a comment...*sigh*

My gut says: propogate the timeout as a `Maybe`/`Nullable`.

Reasoning:

- Probably no one subscribing to this cares what the reason it failed to produce a value was, they just care that a next value was unavailable for some reason. (Of course, I'm making a lot of assumptions here)

To whit, I'd follow the `Timeout` call with a `Catch` that would inject/return a "null value" (defined however you'd like - `Maybe`, `Nullable<T>`, etc), thus making the "shape" of the resulting stream way more clear to any subscribers.

Comment: Maybe (:P) not an answer, but looks good to me. I had briefly looked at `Catch` but couldn't work out which Observable to give it as an argument. I'd forgotten about `Observable.Return`...

Comment: @Benjol Yeah, I actually used that approach on this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782742/reactive-subscription-to-event-not-followed-by-different-event-within-a-period-o/14785323#14785323